# Can vscode generate type definitions?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have been using a trick to get quick typings:

[image: Derive typings from actual data]

I derive my typings from actual data:

```
const ParcelFeatureTypeInstance = {"displayFieldName":"NAMECO","fieldAliases":{"PIN":"PIN / Tax Map #","OWNAM1":"Owner Name(MixedCase)",...};
type ParcelFeatureType = typeof ParcelFeatureTypeInstance;
```

But I would like to take it a step further and then copy the actual type definition from the popup window that opens when I hover over the type, but the definition is incomplete:

```
const ParcelFeatureTypeInstance: {
    displayFieldName: string;
    fieldAliases: {
        PIN: string;
        OWNAM1: string;
        OWNAM2: string;
        STREET: string;
        CITY: string;
        STATE: string;
        ZIP5: string;
        NAMECO: string;
        POWNNM: string;
        DEEDDATE: string;
        CUBOOK: string;
        ... 23 more ...;
        OBJECTID: string;
    };
    geometryType: string;
    spatialReference: {
        ...;
    };
    fields: ({
        ...;
    } | {
        ...;
    })[];
    features: {
        ...;
    }[];
}
```

Is there a way to get the full definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare and emit a `.d.ts` file.

Try this.

In example.ts file put your constants and types:

```
const ParcelFeatureTypeInstance = {"displayFieldName":"NAMECO","fieldAliases":{"PIN":"PIN / Tax Map #","OWNAM1":"Owner Name(MixedCase)"}};
export type ParcelFeatureType = typeof ParcelFeatureTypeInstance;
```

In tsconfig.json put at least:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

Then, run the compiler:

```
tsc -p tsconfig.json
```

You obtain a new file `example.d.ts` with the type declarations of your constants an variables.

Comment: great solution!  not as nice as copying out of the idea but it can be done in a standalone project.  Nice!

Comment: This generates type definitions for the entire project instead of one file (or one type)

Comment: @riv, you are right. There is also another bigger difference. If one type is based on another type in the `. d.ts` file, the two definitions where written separatly. But in the popup sometimes the definitions were merged.